# selenium web driver. Unable to locate element by id, xpath

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code, I'm trying to fiend the element using findElement By.xpath or By.id how ever the Element is not found.

The element that Im looking is inside this class:

```
            <a class="menulink" id="menu_link_200" onClick="showSelectedMenu('200','');openFrame('mainFrame','Mediator.jsp?gotouri=ShowFindConsumer.do&amp;menutype=customer')" >
                Customers
            </a>            

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="separateline"></td>
  </tr>
</span>
```

Comment: try to find it by class like this (driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("menulink")))

Comment: Can you share your code? Because HTML looks straightforward. Or is Id dynamically generated or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//Using LinkText
        driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Customers"));

        //Using Class Name
        driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("menulink"));

        //Using CSS Selector
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a#menu_link_200"));
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a.menulink"));
```

Let me know if none of these works. May be sharing complete HTML code would help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you take a screenshot of what you are looking for? It seems that element gets populated when you click on it. The click even calls "openFrame" function (that I need to see the code too). 
So, if I'm supposed to answer you blind folded, I'll say that you need to first invoke .click on the link - perhaps by doing *driver.findElement(By.linkText("Customers")).click();* - and then see the added HTML content.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that my code is inside a frame, so I used:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("menuFrame");
```

Now it's working.